# Read meta tags from url to fetch image like facebook in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to read image from url and display it in `UIImageView` like Facebook or Twitter do, when you share a url in post.

So far in my knowledge, I need to read the meta tag `<meta property="og:image" content="" />`, but I did not find any way for this in iOS.

I am wondering if there is a way for this, any example code will be appreciated.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: I didn't mean to recommend any tool. I just need example code. edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I used Fizu and SWXMLHash. Fizu to get the head of the HTML document, and SWXMLHash to extract the meta tag for the og:image.

```
import UIKit
import Fuzi
import SWXMLHash

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.foxnews.com/entertainment/2016/04/25/megyn-kelly-will-interview-donald-trump-on-fox-tv-special.html") else {
            print("Invalid URL!")
            return
        }
        guard let html = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
            print("No data returned!")
            return
        }

        guard let htmlString = String(data: html, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) else {
            print ("Invalid data!")
            return
        }

        do {
            let doc = try HTMLDocument(string: htmlString, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(doc.head)  // gets <head> element

            guard let stringValue = doc.head?.description else {
                print("no string")
                return
            }

            let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(stringValue)

            let imageURL = try xml["head"]["meta"].withAttr("property", "og:image").element?.attributes["content"]
            print(imageURL)

        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @nsirlconnection for helping me extract the head from the HTML document!